# Is Java synchronized lock key the same for all synchronized methods of the same object?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

If I have two or more synchronized methods then the lock key is the same for all synchronized methods? With other words if a thread is in a synchronized method then if any other thread wants to access some **other** synchronized method then has to be wait for first thread to end even if the methods are different?

Comment: Yes, that is true as long as you synchronize on the same object

Comment: So many similar questions on SO that even SO's own search found two of them on its own and put them in the "related" sidebar.

Comment: Just a tip: Don't think about synchronizing _methods._ Methods don't need protection. What needs protection is the _data_ on which the methods operate. If you have two or more methods that can be called from different threads to operate on the same data, then those methods _absolutely should_ lock the same lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.
For a more elaborate answer, read on.

From my favourite book on Java, [Head First Java](https://www.wickedlysmart.com/head-first-java/)

> Every **object** has a lock. Most of the time, the lock is unlocked, and
> you can imagine a virtual key sitting with it. Object locks come into
> play only when there are synchronized methods. 
>  
>  When an
> object has one or more synchronized methods, a thread can enter a
> synchronized method only if the thread can get the key to the object’s
> lock! 
> **The locks are not per method, they are per object.**  
>  If an object has two synchronized methods, it does not simply mean that you
> can’t have two threads entering the same method. It means you can’t
> have two threads entering any of the synchronized methods.
>  
> Think about it. If you have multiple methods that can potentially act
> on an object’s instance variables, all those methods need to be
> protected with synchronized.
>  The goal of synchronization is to
> protect critical data. But remember, you don’t lock the data itself,
> you synchronize the methods that access that data.
>  
>  So what
> happens when a thread is cranking through its call stack (starting
> with the run() method) and it suddenly hits a synchronized method?
>
> The thread recognizes that it needs a key for that object before
> it can enter the method. It looks for the key (this is all handled by
> the JVM; there’s no API in Java for accessing object locks), and if
> the key is available, the thread grabs the key and enters the method.
>
> From that point forward, the thread hangs on to that key like the
> thread’s life depends on it. The thread won’t give up the key until it
> completes the synchronized method.
>  So while that thread is holding
> the key, no other threads can enter any of that object’s synchronized
> methods, because the one key for that object won’t be available.

TL;DR:

Every Java object has a lock.
**That is, the locks are not per method, they are per object.**

Now, a lock has only one key.
Most of the time, the lock is
unlocked and nobody cares.
But if an object has
`synchronized` methods, a
thread can enter one of the
`synchronized` methods ONLY
if the key for the **object’s lock**
is available. In other words,
only if another thread hasn’t
already grabbed the one key(by entering a `synchronized` function).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer posted above, I will try to explain to the best of my knowledge:

Synchronized methods inside a class can be static or non-static

- In case of static methods, the lock is at class level. So no matter how many different instances of the class you have, only one thread can access a method at a time. If the first thread from one instance of the class is inside one of the syncd methods, another thread accessing the same of different syncd method in the same class with same/different instance of class would have to wait until the first thread releases the lock at class level.
- For non-static methods, the lock is at instance/object level. Which means 2 threads from 2 separate instances of this class can access the same method at the same time because the lock objects are 2 different instances of this class.